# Question about proving a survey sampling problem

Tags: statistics, sampling

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3RGi.png)
I'm confused about (iii) only, I have no idea about where to start. Please help me out;)

Comment: Hi! take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as is written your question could attract downvote. Try to avoid "no clue questions" and let us see what you've tried sharing your work/thoughts.